# How to get the hypperref label for the footnotemark of a figure caption sending you to the right place in the list of figures?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I have some little issue about the `hypperref` package.

I used some footnotes to cite the source of my figures.

To do that, I just used :

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
Blabla
\caption{Blobloblo.  D'où vient cette figure?\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Elle vient de là , elle vient du blues.}
```

This solution works well with the `hyperref` package, when you click on the footnote mark, you're redirected to the footnote.

The main problem is in the list of figures. When I click on the footnote mark, I'm going back to the main page, as if the list of figures couldn't make the link between the footnote mark in the list of figures and the command `\footnotemark`.

Is the a way to fix this ?

Comment: The easiest way: don't put the footnote mark in the list of figures: `\caption[<goes in the list>]{<goes below figure>}` => `\caption[Blobloblo.  D'où vient cette figure?]{Blobloblo.  D'où vient cette figure?\protect\footnotemark}`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that's actually helpful.

Is there still a possible way to keep the footnote mark and have the mark in the list of figures get you to the right footnote ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way: don't put the footnote mark in the list of figures:

```
\caption[<goes in the list>]{<goes below figure>}
```

For your example:

```
\caption[Blobloblo. D'où vient cette figure?]{%
  Blobloblo. D'où vient cette figure?\protect\footnotemark}.
```